# Django - Update field when datetime field expires

Tags: python, django

I am looking for a solution to update my field when DateTime field expires.

So basically, what I want is let's say DateTime is set for an hour from now, I want to make it that when the current time gets to that set time, it updates another field "missed" to True

Process:
Field = 2021/05/05 16:24
Time gets to 16:24
It gets triggered -> Field missed gets changed to True

Comment: You may be able to use something like celery or cron to schedule tasks

Comment: I also recommend the use of scheduled tasks initiated with signals from your app

Answer (score 0):

This package: https://pypi.org/project/schedule/ should be enough to setup schedule everytime model is created possibly in post save signal.

If this is new Django >= 3.1 you can easily use Celery beat with some broker like redis and rabbitmq but I think that would be overkill if you are not already using these technologies